# Grid column gap causing grid item overflow

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to create a 12-column grid just like Bootstrap one but with CSS3 Grid.

But I got a huge problem: If I have **8-column** item and the **gap is 40px**, then the min width is `40 * 8 = 320px` or else it will overflow.

I made an example here https://codepen.io/hrsetyono/pen/mpKxba

Is there any syntax to fix that? There's not much resource on this other than basic introduction.

Comment: Not sure what you're after. With multiple levels of grid containers and fixed grid-gaps you have the potential for overflow.

Comment: Also, please post your code in the question itself. It will make the question self-sufficient and you'll reduce the chance of having it closed.

Comment: @Michael_B Sorry for late reply, I have posted it as codepen.

Comment: @Michael_B I'm trying to convert my Float column to CSS3 Grid. If I set a column to `9fr` out of 12, I want it to span 75% no matter the screen size.

Comment: Posted some duplicates that may shed some light. If not, let me know and I'll re-open the question.

Comment: The suggested duplications are not dealing exactly with that problem. I also have the problem with grid-gap, that it takes eg. 20px gap * 24 columns = 480px width. Even though I make two columns with a span 10 and 14. The gap applies to EACH column.

Comment: I really agree with @Stefan 's comment. Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: I suppose that it makes sense that the absolute minimum width of a 12-column grid must be its gap * 11 (in this case `40px * 11 = 440px`), else I'm not sure how we would expect the grid to behave given 12 columns with an item in each.

The only workaround I can come up with is to use the lowest number of columns possible. So instead of using a 12-column layout with items spanning 8 and 4 columns respectively – use a 3 column layout with items spanning 2 and 1 columns instead. I admit, also coming from bootstrap, this might not be the workaround one was hoping for.

Comment: Could you please consider reopening this issue? @MichaelBenjamin